# Magento 2 Frontend interview questions

Tags: magento2, frontend

I would be grateful if you leave a questions about the frontend development on m2. Maybe someone remembers the questions asked at the interview. Which topics do you need to know in the first place, and which are secondary? Did you write some code during the interview?